# How to use data wedge to connect to non scanner bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth, zebra-printers, datawedge

I have a use case for connecting with a arbitrary bluetooth device (not a scanner). I have the following questions -

- Is it possible to connect data wedge to a random bluetooth device to send and receive data? I was unable to find any example online in docs or elsewhere. The idea is that the bluetooth device will dump data to its outputstream, and i am hoping data wedge can pick it up and insert in my app field.
- Can data wedge also send requests to the bluetooth device? ( Or can it only be a listener and receive data? ) If yes, how to we configure the request string and frequency.
- In our use case the data is a long string (eg - "a,b,c,d"). My idea is to send this string to a text field and then segregate it in application itself.
- Our use case is for TC 56 devices. As i understand it, the application app listens for the intent data wedge generates post scanning. Can it work seamless on laptops as well? The service in our use case is a web app.

Comment: Have you found any solution or guidance on this.Please share

Comment: Nope. I wasn't able to move forward on this.